# Definition of Null Hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry

I am a physics student confused with the notion of null hypersurface, so sorry if this question is very simple.

Given a manifold $M$ and a hypersurface $H$ defined on it, we can always take the hypersurface to be locally equal to a level set of a scalar function $f$ (I think). Given a certain point $P$, we can thus consider the vector  $g^{ab}\nabla_{b} f$ and notice it is orthogonal to the subspace $T_{P}H$ of the tangent space  $T_{P}M$. $H$ is said to be a null hypersurface if and only if $g^{ab}\nabla_{b} f$ is tangent to $H$.

Now, I can understand that, if $g^{ab}\nabla_{b} f$ is tangent to $H$, then, since $g^{ab}\nabla_{b} f$ is orthogonal to $T_{P}H$, $g^{ab}\nabla_{b} f$ has zero length. Thus, the metric on $T_{P}H$ is degenerate and the name "null hypersurface" is appropriate.

What is not clear to me is that even if $g^{ab}\nabla_{b} f$ has non null length, it might be possible to engineer a situation in which the metric on $T_{P}H$ is still degenerate. It  would make sense to call $H$ a null hypersurface in that case. So, is this situation possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. If $L$ is a null hypersurfce of a Lorentzian manifold $M$, then $TL^{\perp}$   is a one-dimensional null distribution contained in $TL$ ($TL$ is the tangent bundle).

If $f$ is a function such that (al least locally) $f^{-1}(c)=L$, then $g(v,\nabla f)=0$ for all $v\in TL$ and thus $\nabla f\in TL^{\perp}$ and $\nabla f$ is a null vector field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay. I am not very familiar with bundles, but isn't your first statement precisely what I'm asking to prove?

Comment: In retrospect, my question was really simple and this answer is right. Thanks.